# Modify multiple rows on uitableview on view load

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that should have 33 rows.  Each row represents a specific time slot in a day.  When the view that holds the table view loads, I need it to populate each row accordingly.

I have an array of reservation objects that gets passed to the view.  Each reservation contains a slot number, a reservation name and the duration of the reservation in slots.

What is the best way to populate the table, I am currently iterating through the array of reservations in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method.

This is not giving me the results or the behavior I am expecting. The performance is extremly poor as it keeps iterating through loops and cells that shouldn't be blue are blue after scrolling.  What is the best way to approach this?  I have included the code below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 33;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *timeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", (indexPath.row + 14.0 ) / 2.0];
    timeStamp = [timeStamp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".50" withString:@":30"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: ", timeStamp];

    for (Reservation *temp in bookingsArray) {
        if ((temp.slotNumber - 1) == indexPath.row) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", timeStamp, temp.reservationName];
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        for (NSNumber *tempNo in temp.slotIdentifiers) {
            if ([tempNo intValue] -1 == indexPath.row) {
                //cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: Booked", timeStamp];
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

UPDATE
Trying the following gives me strange behaviour where all the cells turn blue after I start scrolling.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    bookManager = appDelegate.bookingManager;
    bookingsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[bookManager getBookingsForCourt:1 onDate:[NSDate date]]];
    namesArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    slotIndexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

    for (int c = 0; c < 33; c++) {
        [namesArray setObject:@"Available" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:c]];
    }

    for (Reservation *temp in bookingsArray) {
        [namesArray setObject:temp.reservationName forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:temp.slotNumber]]; 
        for (NSNumber *slotNo in temp.slotIdentifiers) {
            [slotIndexSet addIndex:[slotNo intValue] + 1];
        }
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *timeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", (indexPath.row + 14.0 ) / 2.0];
    timeStamp = [timeStamp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".50" withString:@":30"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: ", timeStamp];
    cell.textLabel.text = [namesArray objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]; 

    if ([slotIndexSet containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
       cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things to speed this up:

- Convert `bookingsArray` to a `bookingBySlotNumber` array in such a way that the object at index `i` has `slotNumber - 1` equal to `i`. You can do it by iterating over the original bookings array when you receive it.
- Create a [`NSIndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) called `isBookedBySlotNumber` containing indexes of items that have been booked. You can prepare it by going through all `Reservation.slotIdentifiers`, and marking the indexes of `isBookedBySlotNumber` for items that have been booked.

With these two pre-processed items in place, you can eliminate the nested loops altogether: the outer one will be replaced by a lookup in `bookingBySlotNumber`, and the inner one - by a loopup in `isBookedBySlotNumber`.

Comment: I have tried this and the performance is much better.  However, I am still getting an issue where all the cells are turning blue **after** i start scrolling through the list. I will update my answer.  Thanks

Comment: @BON "all the cells are turning blue after i start scrolling through the list" This is because your code's setting the background color is a "one-way street": once the cell turns blue, it never goes back, even after the reuse. To address the issue, add an `else` branch to `if ([slotIndexSet containsIndex:indexPath.row])` statement.